# MySQL values that do not exist in IN statement

Tags: mysql, subquery, having

If the fruits table of my database contains

1. apples
2. pears

and my `IN` statement contains

1. pears
2. apples
3. bananas

How do I find the value(s) that exist in the `IN` statement but do NOT exist in the database?    So in the case the return would be bananas.  The goal is to find misspelled fruits in the `IN` statement.  I tried a subquery along with the `HAVING` clause but couldn't manage to make it work myself.

Edited to fix the contradictory description pointed out by @Xavier-Holt

Comment: Could you please post the query you tried? Thanks!

Comment: Your example and your description contradict each other...  Can you make sure `bananas` is in the right place in your example?

Comment: Your absolutely correct @XavierHolt.  I've fixed it, thank you.

Comment: @Asad I don't have my attempts from the other day but it was something like this: select fruit from (select count(fruit) from fruits where fruit in ('pear', 'apples', 'bananas') group by fruit) having count < 1

Answer (score 1):

You can write:

```
SELECT misspelled_fruit
  FROM (       SELECT 'pears' misspelled_fruit
         UNION SELECT 'apples'
         UNION SELECT 'bananas'
       ) t
 WHERE misspelled_fruit NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT fruit FROM fruits )
;
```

Comment: Sorry @ruakh I can't figure out how to apply this to my situation.  Can you clarify?  My list in real life is 126 entries and I'm looking for what is in the IN statement but not in the DB.

Comment: @JSP: If you want to embed those 126 list-entries directly in your query, then the `SELECT 'pears' misspelled_fruit UNION SELECT 'apples' UNION SELECT 'bananas'` part will be much longer, but otherwise the same. Alternatively, you can put them in a temporary table for purposes of selection.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Fruit NOT IN ('pears', 'apples', 'bananas')
```

That would return things like

```
peers
appels
bannannas
```

Comment: That gives the opposite of what the OP is looking for ("the value(s) that exist in the `IN` statement but do NOT exist in the database", i.e. "misspelled fruits in the `IN` statement"). *Edited to add:* Actually, Xavier Holt points out in a comment above that the question contradicts itself on this point. So, maybe not.